# Any stl/boost type which represents a pair with ordered elements?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I'm just wondering if there is any stl/boost type which implements the following.

I need a pair that keeps its elements in ordered state according to the provided binary predicate, i.e. always corresponds to the condition `Predicate(pair.first, pair.second) == true`.

To be more concrete, I need a pair which stores its elements in decreasing order, i.e.
for any pair `pair.first < pair.second`

Comment: Interesting.  How would keep that predicate matching?  Would the `pair` type need to be constant once initialized?

Comment: Are `first` and `second` both of the same type?

Comment: Sounds like you need a wrapper on `std::pair` that enforces the ordering at construction and alteration time?

Comment: @sftrabbit, it my case they have the same type.

Comment: @Steve Townsend, it's a good idea. Maybe even the best, if there is no out-of-box stl/boost structure for my purposes.

Comment: I think your requirement is quite specialized, I cannot see any 'out of the box' to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems impossible if first second is fields as in your example, because when use change one of them no any method of pair will be called. If it's method it's quite easy to do this:

```
class UnorderePair{
    T first_, second_;
    T& first(){
         return predicate(first_, second_)? first_: second_;
    }
    T& second(){
         return !predicate(first_, second_)? first_: second_;
    }

};
```

Comment: Thank you for for the recipe, but it's interesting to find something standard for my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::set`, or create an adapter for it that reserves 2 element in the ctor and discards any append/prepend/whatever that would break the class invariant that says `assert ( length == 2)`.

Comment: Keeping the values in dynamically allocated nodes (as `std::set` does) would be rather inefficient.

Comment: well then an adapter on a tuple